# .NET core MVC Make input element conditionally Readonly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am a new .NET programmer. I have the following `input`:

```html
<input asp-for="FirstName"
       id="FirstName"
       class="form-control"
       value="@Context.Request.Query["FirstName"]"
       type="text"
       readonly="readonly" />
```

If the textbox has data, I want the textbox to be `readonly`, if there is no data in the textbox, then the user can input data. Can anybody give advice?

Comment: You can use Razor syntax

Comment: Try `<input asp-for="FirstName" id="FirstName" class="form-control" value="@Context.Request.Query["FirstName"]" type="text" readonly="@string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Context.Request.Query["FirstName"])" />`

Comment: @MordZuber `readonly` is a [boolean attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/readonly). It works if it's present, not if it has certain content.

Comment: sorry, I was used to a in house framework that removed `readonly=false` during build.

Comment: This might work though `<input asp-for="FirstName" id="FirstName" class="form-control" value="@Context.Request.Query["FirstName"]" type="text" @(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Context.Request.Query["FirstName"]) ? "readonly" : "") />`

Comment: Thanks MordZuber and GSerg, it is amazing for your so quickly response me. i use @(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Context.Request.Query["FirstName"]) ? "readonly" : "")  not work. The Code show "readonly"Missing attribute name.

Comment: it seems readonly="@string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Context.Request.Query["FirstName"])" /> is work but not my expect result as textbox empty is show readonly.thank you for support!

Comment: hello, anybody can help??thxthx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the textbox has data, I want the textbox to be readonly, if there
> is no data in the textbox, then the user can input data. Can anybody
> give advice?

According to your code and description, it seems that you want to set the textbox to be read-only based on the `FirstName` query string parameter. I suggest you could try to use the following code (use [Razor syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-5.0)):

```
@model MVCDemo.Models.Customer

<form asp-action="Create">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div> 
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="FirstName" class="control-label"></label>
        @{
            var value = Context.Request.Query["FirstName"].ToString();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                <input asp-for="FirstName" id="FirstName" class="form-control" value="@value" type="text" />
            }
            else
            {
                <input asp-for="FirstName" id="FirstName" class="form-control" value="@value" type="text" readonly />
            }

        } 
        <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```

The screenshot as below:

[image]

Besides, if you want to make the textbox read-only after entering some value, you could use JQuery to add or remove the `readonly` attribute on the textbox.

Comment: woooo, so amazing!!! it is my expect result! thank you support and teaching!!!

Answer (score -2):

You can do something like this

```
       @{
            var firstname= Context.Request.Query["FirstName"];
        }
        <input asp-for="FirstName" id="FirstName" class="form-control" 
            value="@Context.Request.Query["FirstName"]" type="text" 
            readonly="@(Context.Request.Query["FirstName"]=="" ? "False" : "True")">
```

Comment: thank shehab quickly response me! thank you for your advise !

Comment: it's not work. The text box empty or null to be readonly/3\